# creating web form to display questions from a database

Tags: php, mysql, html

P.S. I am new to php & webform scripting;

Currently I have the following multiple choice question table inside MySQL database :

```
     |MCQ_ID|Question|Opt_1|Opt_2|Opt_3|Opt_4|Opt_5|
     |1|What is the port|23|21|22|80|53
```

My objective is to create a quiz in a web form, using php scripting where 
(1) The Questions are selected from the database & displayed in a multiple choice form with only a single answer to each question
(2) Each webform should display only one question as there will be a timer to record the amount of time spend at a particular question.

Below is my begining script & how should I go from here to achieve my above objectives?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type='text/css'>
                #wrapper {
                    width:950px;
                    height:auto;
                    padding: 13px;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    background-color: #fff;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="#e1e1e1">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <center><font fact="Andalus" size="5">Test Quiz</font></center>
                <br /><br /><br /><br />
            </div>

            <?php
                //Start Variables
                $username   =   "root";
                $password   =   "";
                $database   =   "Test";
                //End Variables

                //Connect To Database
                $link   =   mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password) or die ('Could not connect :'.  mysql_error());
                mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

                //SQL Get Questions
                $query  =   "SELECT * FROM MCQuestionBank";
                $result =   mysql_query($query) or die ('Query failed:'. mysql_error());
                $row    =   mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                //Get results
                /*
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    {
                        echo '<br> QuestionName : ' .$row{'Question'} ;
                        echo '<br> Option 1 : ' .$row{'MCQ_Opt1'};
                        echo '<br> Option 2 : ' .$row{'MCQ_Opt2'};
                        echo '<br> Option 3 : ' .$row{'MCQ_Opt3'};
                        echo '<br> Option 4 : ' .$row{'MCQ_Opt4'};
                        echo '<br> Option 5 : ' .$row{'MCQ_Opt5'};
                    }
                */
                mysql_free_result($result); 
                mysql_close($link);
            ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if a question needs 6+ options?

Comment: I keeping it at 5 options for this set of multiple choice questions.

Comment: How about the PHP scripting part? It seems quite confusing to me, any guidance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That table structure is going to be unmanageable.  If you're going to use a database you need to normalize it.  Questions go in one table. Answers in another.  That way is much more flexible.  What are you are going to do when, for example, a question needs to have more (or less than) 5 choices?

Get some general background on relational databases and then come back to the problem.  This might be a good start:

http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx

Comment: How about the PHP scripting part? It seems quite confusing to me, any guidance ?

Comment: If you want to write PHP you need to learn PHP.  Have you gotten a beginning book on PHP?  Start there and come back if you have specific questions.  If you don't want to go to that effort you would probably be better off getting an off the shelf quiz creator (there are hundreds of them).

Answer (score 1):

- You can use radio button to display your options

[www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)

- You can use HTML form to submit the answer by user back to the server.

[www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

- Unless you've the correct answer stored in the database, you have to correct the answers manually. For a multiple choice questions, it is very easy to store the correct answer in database. Have one more column to denote the correct answer.

[www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) will be a good starting point to learn these stuff.

Comment: Regarding the correcting of the answers, what difference will it make / which is the better option if i : (1) Store the answers in a table in the database & compare the answers using PHP scripting (if there is a way to do that)? There may be a chance that I may randomize the order of the questions. It has been stretching my brain cells for a while now.

Comment: It is possible to store the correct answer in DB, and compare them using PHP, as I have already mentioned you've to read about HTML forms and see this page http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp, simple examples in these pages will help you understand how that can be done. Also yeah you can randomize the order there is a rand() function in PHP, which you can make use of.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this properly is no simple task. You should use at least three different tables:
1. A table with your questions and a unique id. 
2. A table with your answers, the id of the question they go to, and a boolean that indicates whether it is true or false. 
3. A way to track your users' answers. This should, at minimum, store a session id and an id to the answer. Without this, you will not be able to do a question per page properly (right now you are dumping all the questions onto one page). 
4. A user table is almost non-optional, with a field for it's unique id in the above table (instead of a session id).

Making these tables talk to each other is not that difficult if you read up on JOIN queries.

Once you have a good database set up, you are ready to look at the php. We have all started out doing it your way and we foresee a lot of hair pulling in your future.